# Elasticsearch cluster url when connecting with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I have an 3-nodes Elasticsearch cluster with 1 master and 2 data nodes.
Let's say their private IPs are `10.10.10.1`, `10.10.10.2`, `10.10.10.3`.

I'm wiring up a Logstash to the cluster, and I'm confused about which value should I set output.elasticsearch.hosts.

Should it be something like `"10.10.10.1:9200,10.10.10.2:9200,10.10.10.3:9200"`, or just specifying one data node is enough?

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `hosts` option of the `elasticsearch` output you should set your data nodes, if your master node is a master exclusive node you can leave it out the configuration, but you can put the other two data nodes.

Logstash will load balance the requests between those nodes.

You should use it in this format:

```
hosts => ["host1:9200", "host2:9200", "hostN:9200"]
```